# Hide wp-login.php but not the widget

Tags: login, security, wp-login-form

I have a website which is still under nascent construction stage: http://42charts.com .

Lately I find that couple of users are registering themselves in my site. It seems like a bot as the mails IDs are weird, users do not use the site. Moreover my `wp-login.php` page does not have direct link (the homepage login site is a social login through wp-social-login plugin integrated with Login-with-ajax - ajax does not work right now but  its for future).

I do not want a user to be able to see the login/registration page, *but* I want them to be able to see the login option at the page top, which comes through a wp-social-login widget. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: If I understand you, and I am not sure that I do, then "no", you can't really do that.

Comment: *Lately I find that couple of users are registering themselves in my site. It seems like a bot as the mails IDs are weird, users do not use the site.* One of our developer solved this problem in some of our company's client's site using **[SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam](http://wordpress.org/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/) plugin**. It adds a login captcha so bot like this goes out. I din't tested it, he's responsible for adding it. So, I'm just recommending it, not assuring. :)

Comment: I have functions that I use on my website that completely restrict direct access to the login and registration pages. This functions also redirect these spambots to the index page. I will post these as soon as I get home from work.